# Spring MVC nested object validation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, nested-class

I have the following code in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "employee/update", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public UpdateEmployeeResponse updateEmployee(@RequestBody @Valid @ModelAttribute("updateEmployeeRequest") UpdateEmployeeRequest updateEmployeeRequest, BindingResult result) {
```

My Request object is as follows

```
public class UpdateEmployeeRequest {
@Valid
@NotNull
private Employee employee;
.
.

public class Employee {
@NotNull
protected String id;
@NotNull
protected String name;
.
.
```

When I send JSON request like (id is missing)

```
{employee:{name:"cc",phone:"9876543210",dept:"dpt"}}
```

My Request is not getting validated by spring(it doesn't show any error even if a field is missing). I have gone through the following threads but no luck.

- [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244639/spring-mvc-nested-model-validation)
- [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680730/validate-a-list-of-nested-objects-with-spring-validator)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add the htmpl form code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore any unknown properties in JSON input without exception try using `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`.

Try this out

**Employee.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Employee
{
 @NotNull
 protected String id;
 @NotNull
 protected String name;
 .
 .
```

**UpdateEmployeeRequest.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UpdateEmployeeRequest {
 @Valid
 @NotNull
 private Employee employee;
 .
 .
```

Comment: My question is the validation itself is not working. I want to make it work.

Comment: @arjuncc you mean validation fails during deserializing  json to java

Comment: exactly, i dont have any error in when i check hasError method in BindingResult.

Comment: @arjuncc can you post your jsp page

Comment: The question has nothing to do with ignoring properties or jsp (or other) front-end code.  The question is why aren't nested object properties having their @NotNull validation checked on the server side when it receives a JSON request.  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention whether you have a validator in the project.  In Maven add these dependencies:

```
        <!-- Bean validation -->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
     </dependency>
```